# How do update to column from excel file using SSIS?

Tags: excel, ssis

i'm trying to update a specific column from excel file using ssis, with the "execute sql task". is this posible or exists other way?

i was expecting update using execute sql task, but i dont understand how configurate this "task" for resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the Execute SQL Task, in the SQLStatement :

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET ColumnName = 'NewValue' WHERE yourCondition
```

You need to to replace [Sheet1$] with the actual name of the sheet in your Excel file and ColumnName with the name of the column you want to update, then adjust the WHERE clause to specify the condition for the rows you want to update.